# xml data extraction, need to extract last 10 alphabets

Tags: xml

Iam using xml  for automation proj, iam having following xml doc

```
<output>
    <line index="1">Copyright 2010 BMC Software Ltd, Version: 1.6.2  </line>
    <line index="2">Connecting to remote service...</line>
    <line index="3">Connected to remote host.</line>
    <line index="4">SERVICE_NAME: sqlagent$sqlinst </line>
    <line index="5">TYPE: 10 WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  </line>
    <line index="6">STATE: 4 RUNNING </line>
    <line index="7">(STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)</line>
    <line index="8">WIN32_EXIT_CODE: 0  (0x0)</line>
    <line index="9">SERVICE_EXIT_CODE: 0  (0x0)</line>
    <line index="10">CHECKPOINT: 0x0</line>
    <line index="11">WAIT_HINT: 0x0</line>
    <line index="12">Remote application exited with code: 0 </line>
</output>
```

I need to get output of line index 6 as running or stopped state , so i have used following xml sylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vlength">
   <xsl:copy-of select="/output/line[@index=6]"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="string-length($vlength)"/>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">                   
<dayOfMonth>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(/output/line[@index=6],0,40)"/>
</dayOfMonth>

</xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but somehow i am not getting desired result, can you please help me out
following is snapshot

[image]

so i need output as running  or stopped
its 9 alphabets from last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following : substring('string',9) -starting from 9th index,it will print the rest of the string.

```
 <xsl:value-of select="substring(output/line[6],9)"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following XSLT to get the value of the **last 9 characters** of the string.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="status" select="output/line[@index = 6]" />
    <xsl:variable name="stringLength" select="string-length($status)" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <status>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring($status, $stringLength - 9, $stringLength))" />
        </status>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This provides the required output as below

```
<status>RUNNING</status>
```